# robot framework : grep ip from list and put it in another list

Tags: robotframework

I have following list as an example, how to grep IP from the following list and put it in another list using robot framework libraries? This is just an example, this list could be pretty large based on size of routing table.

```
${routes} = ['201', '0000.aaaa.bbbb', '10.10.1.11', 'BGP', 'L,', '2', 'Local', 'leaf1#','202', '0000.cccc.bbbb', '10.10.1.12', 'BGP', 'L,', '2', 'Local', 'leaf2#','201', '0000.dddd.bbbb', '10.10.1.21', 'BGP', 'L,', '2', 'Local', 'leaf1#']
```

new list should look like following once with just IPs in the list:

```
${routes-ip} =['10.10.1.11','10.10.1.12','10.10.1.21']
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the large list, checking is each element one of the ones you look for; if yes, put it in a "result list":

```
${target values}=    Create List    10.10.1.11    10.10.1.12    10.10.1.21
${a very long list with all values}=    Keyword That Returns The List, Or Some Other Way You Get Them

${found values}=     Create List    # an empty one, will hold all values in the long that were in the ${target values}

FOR    ${value}    IN    @{a very long list with all values}
    ${this is a target value}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    List Should Contain Value    ${target values}    ${value}
    Run Keyword If    ${this is a target value}    Append To List    ${found values}    ${value}
END

Log To Console    All target values found in the long list: ${found values}
```

Comment: Thx but list in ${target values} is unknown. I gave that for an example output. is there a way to slice?

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood your question - so, you have a list of strings, and want to filter all that match IP addresses in them?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Regex to get the Ip's

E.g.

```
Create IP Address List
   @{routes}  Create List  
   ...  201  0000.aaaa.bbbb  10.10.1.11  BGP  L,  2  Local  leaf1#  
   ...  202  0000.cccc.bbbb  10.10.1.12  BGP  L,  2  Local  leaf2#  
   ...  201  0000.dddd.bbbb  10.10.1.21  BGP  L,  2  Local  leaf1#

   @{routes-ip}  Create List 

   FOR  ${element}  IN  @{routes}
       ${status}  Run Keyword And Return Status  Should Match Regexp  ${element}  \\b\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\b
       Run Keyword If  "${status}"=='True'  Append To List    ${routes-ip}  ${element}
   END
   Log To Console  ${routes-ip}
```